# Understanding a component in python guessing game code

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to Python and using some online resources to learn stuff.
I am trying to wrap my head around a guessing game, but I am getting confused by one condition in the code.

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
     if guess_count < guess_limit:
          guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
          guess_count += 1
     else:
          out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
     print("You Lose!")
else:
     print("You Win!")
```

I ma able to follow the code, but get lost at not(out_of_guesses) condition in the while loop. Can someone explain this part?

From what I understand, it says that when the secret_word is not equal to the guess and out_of_guess is true, keep looping, else break out of the loop. I am probably wrong. Can someone please help me understand this.

Comment: No, it says that when the `secret_word` is not equal to the `guess` and `out_of_guesses` is **not** true, keep looping.

Comment: but out_of_guess is 'false' here, right (based on the initial condition)?

Comment: So I have 2 conditions in if loop:
1. when the guess word is equal to the secret key word, what will be the out_of_guess condition?
2. when the out_of_guess is true (if condition goes to else), the  guess word is still equal to the secret key word, so how does it break out of the loop?

Comment: In simple terms: it keeps looping as long as you don't guess the secret word *and* you don't run out of guesses. Otherwise it exists the loop.

Comment: Okay, you said that keep looping if words are not equal, and out_of_guess is false. But then we are using a ‘not’ keyword in while, meaning while loop runs until words are equal and/or the out_of_guess is false?

Comment: Why do we negate the whole loop boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split into two parts, you have:

```
guess != secret_word
```

This means `guess` does not equal `secret_word`

<sup>*clearly*</sup>

And

```
not(out_of_guesses)
```

`not out_of_guesses` is checking that variable is `False`

Where `not` flips the `bool` into the opposite.

Example:

```py
>>> x = False
>>> x
False
>>> not x
True
```

---

The `and` means both conditions must be `True` for the `while` loop to run

---

**Edit**

You will leave the `while` loop when at least one condition is `False`.

The first condition will be `False` when `guess = input("Enter a guess: ")` is the `secret_word`

The second condition will be `False` when `out_of_guesses = True` (that line runs). Which will run when `guess_count < guess_limit`

Comment: Do you know why we are negating the boolean value in the while condition?

Comment: @Vedant, because you want to exit when `out_of_guesses == True`. i.e. you need to exit the *guessing* loop when you have no more guesses. And a `while` loop only runs when it's condition is `True`. So you need the condition to be `False` to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop means: while `guess` not equal to `secret_word` and not `out_of_guesses` - which means your `out_of_guesses` must be `false` => so that `not(out_of_guesses)` can be `True`; then the loop keeps running, otherwise, breaking out of the loop.